# Powershell running on jenkins blocks script execution when the command return an error

Tags: powershell, jenkins

I have configured and script on jenkins with powershell command:

```
pipeline {
    agent any
    stages {
        stage('Connecting VPN') {
            steps {
                script {
                    bat label: 'Environment', script: 'echo hello world!'
                }
                script
                {
                    pwsh '''
                        $session1 = New-PSSession -HostName 172.17.1.64 -UserName apcor:mydom -SSHTransport
                        echo Uploading files...
                          
                            echo Copying WebApp....
                        }
                    '''
                    }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

But when the New-PSSession fails for any reason, the execution of scripts blocks and i can not control the script.

The Console output :

[Pipeline] {
[Pipeline] pwsh
ssh: connect to host 172.17.1.64 port 22: Connection timed out

and the script keep blocked here...

How could i specify to powershell a non blocking command when an error ocurrs?

Comment: Use Get-NetTCPConnection and see if connection closed after getting error.  Use command on both client and server.  You are using port 22 SSH.  Are both machines Windows?

Comment: Hello jdweng. may be i was not clear. the command block the execution with the error and the script does not continue its execution. My problem is how could i change this behavior?

Comment: You cannot make a connection if first connection doesn't close.  A TCP connection has three properties 1) Source IP 2) Destination IP 3) Port.  SSH is using TCP for transport layer. If first connection doesn't close you can't make a second connection and continue.  You need to get first connection to close.